# stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth causes corners to be blurry

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a box that i want to be expanable only on its width, while still maintaining the rounded corners that I have. I made the graphic in photoshop. and it is exactly 13px wide, so 6 for each corner and 1 for the middle to repeat.

```
UIImage* img = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"screen_displayer_rounded.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:6 topCapHeight:6];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(272.0f, 14.0f, 100.0f, 30.0f);
    UIImageView* imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    [imgView setImage:img];
```

Could anyone tell me why this might be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that you cant just rely stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth to get it to resize correctly.

I normally use the contentStretch property that is available to all UIView subclasses when stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth doesnt work for me.

Checkout the UIView apple docs regarding the contentStretch property.

Comment: -1 because this is plain wrong. stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth works like a charm in many apps I wrote.

Comment: How is this plain wrong? It's great that you have found success using stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth but it doesnt work for all situations. I have used contentStretch on numerous occasions where stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth just didn't cut it.

Answer (score 1):

You should check if the view doesn't end up at a non-integer position. If you choose "Run with performance tool > Core Animation" and check "Color misaligned images", all misaligned images will show purple.

If your image is purple, try to find out which superview is causing this. Look out for things being centered, since that is a common cause for these issues.

Comment: dunno, but it must be in there. It's part of Instruments in XCode 3.

Comment: not seeing it, but i double checked everything i got, no way is the image be placed half on a px and half on another, It looks as if xcode is blurring the actual corners for some reason

Comment: could you post a screenshot? Try putting one bright red pixel in the non-stretchable area, it may shed some light.

Comment: In XCode 4 this is in the iOS Simulator for me

Answer (score 0):

Just checking - are you perhaps viewing a non-retina image on a retina display? This would definitely stretch it out.

Comment: its blurred on both, not just one :(

Comment: If i just add the image, un-stretched the corners are just fine and nice a crisp, but if i even stretch it +1px wider than normal the corners are all still the correct radius, just blurry

Comment: Seeing that you've put the height to 14px, I assume you have the same 6px rounded corner vertically as well. Could you perhaps post the image up here James? Your code looks like it should work out.